# Less installation mac

Tags: macos, installation, less

I've been following this tutorial for installing less on mac (I have 10.7.5). 
http://brianflove.com/2012/09/06/starting-with-less/

I have installed brew and have installed git and node. I get to the final stages and I'm getting the error

> npm: command not found

I have attached an image that shows what happens when I enter **brew doctor** [image]

when I call **brew link node** it then says:

> Error: Could not symlink file:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.25/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h Target
>   /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h already exists. You may
>   need to delete it. To force the link and overwrite all other
>   conflicting files, do:   brew link --overwrite formula_name
>
> To list all files that would be deleted:   brew link --overwrite
>   --dry-run formula_name

I'm not too familiar with command lines so I'd appreciate an explanation on how to overwrite these files.

Comment: The `--overwrite` option is giving you the way to replace the existing file with a symlink.  The command `brew link --overwrite --dry-run node` would show you all the files that would be modified by using that command, without actually doing it.  Once you have done the dry run and verified that you want to do the replacement, then you remove the `--dry-run` option and run the command again.

Comment: when I ran that it said permission denied. can i run chmod on a directory for all the node files?

Comment: Then you would use `sudo brew link --overwrite --dry-run node` to get permission.  I would avoid changing directory permissions unless absolutely necessary...

Comment: Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew link`

Comment: Fun times... okay then, `chmod` and `chgrp` are the next best bet (as found by searching for that error message).  Now I remember why I stopped trying to install extras like this...  It seems to just get messier and messier.